# Using the @ symbol to identify users like twitter does

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I'm creating my own version of twitter, I have no idea how to get my back end php script to pick up the @membername within the entered text. Including multiple @membername's for example @billy @joseph, @tyrone,@kesha message

or

@billy hit up @tyrone he's bugging @kesha about the money you owe him.

Any scripts of use on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: WOW, I really see why Google is going down, I search all night on google for a script for this found nothing. In 5 mins I got great response on here. @Curtisk once I get the user names the message is added to the database and sent to each users timeline. @Dremation, thanks for your answer, I'll definitely give it a try. @Pascal MARTIN thanks for your answer also bro, but your way is a bit above my skill level. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: By any means, I don't think Google is "going down" ...

Comment: Twitter must be easier to build than I thought.

Answer (score 8):

What about using a regex and [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all), like this :

```
$str = "Including multiple @membername's for example @billy @joseph, @tyrone,@kesha message ";
if (preg_match_all('#(@\w+)#', $str, $m)) {
    var_dump($m[1]);
}
```

Which would give you the following output :

```
array
  0 => string '@membername' (length=11)
  1 => string '@billy' (length=6)
  2 => string '@joseph' (length=7)
  3 => string '@tyrone' (length=7)
  4 => string '@kesha' (length=6)
```

Basically, here, the pattern I used in my regex is matching :

- An `@` character
- Any *(more than one)* character that can be inside a word : `\w+`

  - About that, see the [Backslash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php) page, in the [Regular Expressions (Perl-Compatible)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) section of the PHP manual

Comment: Hey Pascal, I'm trying to insert this into the database, with your script I'd need to strip the @ to get the member name of who to send the message to. Help please.

Comment: I tried your way bro, I just keep getting an error on the 1st part of the script. I'm lost on how I can then insert the array into the database after the 1st part anyway.

Comment: How Do you input HTML on this site?


Alright I finally got this thing to output something that's not an error using a combination of your script and another script. I just got an error with yours every time.
Here Is the Script:

$string = $breez;
preg_match_all('#(@\w+)#',$string, $m);
$hypertext = "<a href=http://www.BreezMe.com/>" . $m . "</a>";
$newString = preg_replace('#(@\w+)#', $hypertext, $string);

The output is what gets inserted into the database is this. <br>
<a href=http://www.BreezMe.com/>Array</a> <br>
how do I get it to insert the members name without the @ in front of it?

Comment: Using your method, implode is the only way I can get it to show the names of the members I'm sending the message to, only problem now is it puts all the names of the members in one string. <a href=http://www.BreezMe.com/@test6,@test5,@test2,@test3>@test6,@test5,@test2,@test3</a> I've tried and tried but I can't get it to only put one in then move on to the next, it does it for all of them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you do not want the `@` to be captured, put it outside of the `()`, in the pattern, which would then be : `#@(\w+)#` ;;; to iterate over the names, you can use a `foreach($m[1] as $name) {echo $name . '<br />';}` loop, a treat them one by one : one name per itaration of the loop

Comment: Thanks for you help bro, but All I get is an error message via ajax. It flat out won't work.

Comment: hu ; Ajax ? there must be more going on that you first posted ^^ ;;; can you show us your code and describe both what you're trying to do, and the error you're getting ? *(you can edit your question, if necessary -- or, depending on if the Ajax error is a problem distinct from the OP here, ask a new question)*

Comment: I really wish I know how to format on here but here's the code. 

if(isset($_REQUEST['breez']))
{
$breez=$_REQUEST['breez'];
}
 
if($memid!=""){
 
if($breez==""){
$return['error'] = true;
$return['msg'] = 'No Message.';
}
if ($breez!="") {
$string = $breez;
if (preg_match_all('#@(\w+)#',$string, $m)){
foreach($m[1] as $name) {
 $item==$name;
 }
}
$hypertext = "<a href=http://www.BreezMe.com/$item>" . $item . "</a>";
$newString = preg_replace('#(@\w+)#', $hypertext, $string);

$strsql="INSERT INTO breez(fromid,toid,message,createdate) 
VALUES(\"$memid\",\"$toid\",\"$newString\",now())";

Comment: Finally got it bro, you are right there was some other error going on. I deleted everything and did it from scratch and it works perfectly. I'll have the site up soon to show you your handy work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a PHP library designed to conform to Twitter's standards. It might save you a lot of hassle. It supports autolinking as well as extraction for @screen_names, #hashtags, and @screen_name/lists.

http://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-php

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Wordpress plugin that handles this a long time ago. Here's the function that I use for this.

```
function convert_twitter_link($content) {
    $pattern    = '/\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) /';
    $replace    = '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'.strtolower('\1').'">@\1</a>';
    return preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$content);
}
```

Comment: Dremation provide me with the link to that tutorial please. Just checked your blog for it.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no tutorial. You simply pass the information you want to scan for the @names and it'll return that content back with formatted @names linking to the url. In your case you'd have to change twitter.com to yourdomain.tld

Comment: so in the case of multiple name I should run a while insert loop to insert it into the database?
What I'm trying to do here is get the names from the string and insert the message into a database, so the message then appears in the appropriate users time line. I have everything else I just need this one part. This is on a standalone site not, wordpress.

Comment: I've tried this repeatedly bro it's not working.
here's the script:
if(isset($_REQUEST['breez']))
{
$breez=$_REQUEST['breez'];
}

function convert_twitter_link($breez) {
    $pattern    = '/\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) /';
    $replace    = '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'.strtolower('\1').'">@\1</a>';
    $message= preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$breez);
}

$message comes out blank.

Comment: If thats the case then you'll want to use Pascal MARTIN code example. If you want to display them as links in your content then use my example.

Comment: the var_dump sequence returns and error every time.
I was able to use a mix of his code and another I found similar to your that converts it to a link, however it's giving me a count of the items in the array as the value instead of the names of the members in the array. 

if (preg_match_all('#(@\w+)#',$string, $m)){
$arrays=preg_match_all('#(@\w+)#',$string, $m);
$array = array($arrays);
foreach($array as $item) {
   $m=$item;
} 
$hypertext = "<a href=http://www.BreezMe.com/$m>" . $m . "</a>";
$newString = preg_replace('#(@\w+)#', $hypertext, $string);

Answer (score 0):

All depends on how you set it up...Can your user names have a space in it? If not, then just simply parse the message string for "@" and pick up all characters that come after until you encounter a space...that's a real simple way to get it done.

The other side of the question is what are you doing with the usernames once you do "find" them?

Comment: WOW, I really see why Google is going down, I search all night on google for a script for this found nothing. In 5 mins I got great response on here. 
@Curtisk once I get the user names the message is added to the database and sent to each users timeline. 

@Dremation, thanks for your answer, I'll definitely give it a try.

@Pascal MARTIN thanks for your answer also bro, but your way is a bit above my skill level. I'll give it a try though.