# Need PHP regex to parse Twitter name from subject line

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP and trying to parse this subject line to isolate just the twitter name (@MargyM):

```
Margaret M (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
```

Note that the user name (before the twitter name) can be something else, with parens, so the regex needs to be smart enough to work around that-- i.e. any of these could be valid inputs:

```
Margaret M (:) (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret M ):) (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret M. :) (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret M (-- (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret M ( : (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret M (_: (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
```

So to be clear, the RegEx should **look at the bit of text between the *final* set of parens before "is now following you..." to get the Twitter name.**

EDIT: it's also possible that one or more "@" signs could appear before the twitter name, i.e. anything like this:

```
Margaret @ Minnesota (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret @ Minnesota :-) (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret @ Minnesota (-) (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
Margaret @ Minnesota (tweet @ME!) (@MargyM) is now following you on Twitter
etc.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the @ symbol to identify users like twitter does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540013/using-the-symbol-to-identify-users-like-twitter-does)

Comment: Hi Mario, no, I need something more robust than the simple regex's at that question. Thanks for pointing it out, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=@).*(?=\))/', $subject, $regs)) {
    #$regs[0];
}
```

**After your edit :**

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=@)(?!.*@).*(?=\))/', $subject, $regs)) {
    #$regs[0];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
(?<=     # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   @        # Match the character “@” literally
)
(?!      # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   .        # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *        # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   @        # Match the character “@” literally
)
.        # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *        # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?=      # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   \)       # Match the character “)” literally
)
"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't just look for the first thing after the "@" symbol. I edited my question. added a couple more examples to show more of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/(\(@.+\))/i";
preg_match( $regex , $input , $match );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't just look for the first thing after the "@" symbol. I edited my question. added a couple more examples to show more of what I mean.

Comment: /(/(@[^ ]+/))/i
something like this; it does not use spaces now.

And then you do preg_match_all( $regex , $line , $matches ); Now you just take the last result..

$user = array_pop( $matches ); // should be like this

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

```
/\((@[^)]+)\) is now following you on Twitter/
```

Or alternatively, if the following text isn’t always like that but never contains any `@` itself:

```
/\((@[^)]+)\)(?:[^@]+)$/m
```

You can see a working example of the first [here](http://regexr.com?2v95m) and of the second [here](http://regexr.com?2v95j).